# What's the large pipe on top of M/S Viking Grace?

Tags: ferries, cruising, baltic-sea, viking-line

It looks really weird and I can't understand its purpose. Is it for making the vessel look better? An exhaust? Does anyone know what it it? Apparently it didn't have it in the beginning and it seems it's been moved after being put on the ship. It's rotating and it's glowing during night.

- What is it?
- Why was it moved?

[image: Viking Grace today, with the thing on the center of the ship.]

[image: Viking Grace with the thing in the back]

[image: Viking Grace originally, without the thing.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Maritime Herald](http://www.maritimeherald.com/2017/cruise-ferry-viking-grace-install-turbosail-for-hybrid-usage-of-wind-power/) says it's a "[rotor sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotor_ship)," to supplement the ship's diesel engines.

The Wikipedia article notes fuel savings of up to 20% during favorable wind conditions.